# Function in page called before function in masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have the following functions for language in masterpage:

```
    protected void jezikBA_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Add("language", "ba");
        imgEN = "~/files/images/lang_en_off.gif";
        imgBA = "~/files/images/lang_ba.gif";
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);            
    }


    protected void jezikEN_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Add("language", "en");
        imgEN = "~/files/images/lang_en.gif";
        imgBA = "~/files/images/lang_ba_off.gif";
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
```

and then I have this in page:

```
    if (Session["language"] == "ba" || Session["language"] == null)
    {
               ...
    }
```

The thing is when I change the language, the code which is in page is called before functions for change language in masterpage. This only happens in two places, for others works fine. For this to work, functions in masterpage which change language first need to be called in order to make proper language changes in page, but functions in page are first called and then functions in masterpage which makes this meaningless.

Comment: In which event is the page code being called?

Comment: Functions in masterpage are OnClick and in page are Page_Load

Comment: On the postback when the button is clicked the "language" session variable will have the wrong value but after the redirection it will have the correct variable, which is the page request that gets rendered.  Are you saying the "language" session variable logic does not work correctly after the redirection?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying! Nevertheless, I've solved the problem using javascript.